# Tensorflow: How to access sparse tensor value by index

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I want to access the values of a sparse tensor by indices in constant access time. For example, if I have the sparse tensor represented by:

```
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 3], dense_shape=[3, 4])
```

I would like an operation similar to this:

```
assert sparse[0,0] == 1
assert sparse[1,2] == 3
```

Is there any simple way to do this? I have seen similar examples of this where tf.where is used in combination with tf.gather. This, however, seems like a very inefficient way of accessing these values, as I now (in worst case scenario) have to search through the entire indices tensor in order to find a match (growing linearly with the number of values in the tensor), instead of a constant access time.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get value in constant access time because sparse tensor in Tensorflow is stored in COOrdinate format which does not have any efficient way to access by index or slice in O(1) time.
By the way, you can use `tf.sparse_slice` to access by index which is simpler than using `tf.where` with `tf.gather`.